# redirect to another link using the session PHP + .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website in spanish and english, I have a variable in sessions (php) where I save the lenguage.

localhost < spanish

localhost/eng  < english

I would like if somebody enter to my website localhost and in the session have lenguage english i would like to redirect to localhost/eng

I'm not sure if I can do it with .htaccess else how I do it?

Thank u very much

Comment: Why not using the `header()` function?

Comment: never had heard about that, I try,  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how do that in PHP, no need to use .htaccess

```
if($_SESSION['session'] == 'eng'){
    header("location: localhost/eng");
}
```

Comment: Also make sure you `die();` after calling `header()`, since the code may keep on running and causing some unintended side-effects.